# Can I use a USB drive instead of a micro sd card?

Tags: raspbian, hardware, storage

I have a USB but not a micro SD card. I installed the operating system onto it.

Can I use that as the storage and OS layer for my Raspberry Pi 4?

Comment: this really depends on which Pi you have ... 0, 0W, A, B, A+, B+ and 2B **always** need an sd card with at least `bootcode.bin` on it, the rest of the boot CAN be from USB device .... Pi 3 (not +) needs to boot from SD at least once, then you need to set a "flag", and you can boot from USB from then on ...3B+ or 3A+ can boot from USB as factory default (it has the aforementioned flag pre-set) ... pi4 needs to boot from SD at least once so you can update the EEPROM bootloader to the latest "stable" version

Comment: yes, it is possible using at least a couple of methods

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=pi+gui+on+mac - that's a good place to start

Comment: What Raspberry Pi model do you use?

Comment: It's a raspberry pi 4

Answer (score 3):

Since you have a Raspberry Pi 4 it is possible to get it to boot from USB.

The process to switch from SD card boot to USB boot is demanding that you FIRST boot from a SD card.

So YES you need a SD card.

The process is roughly:

1. Create a bootable SD card with "Raspberry Pi OS"
2. Edit the /etc/default/rpi-eeprom-update
3. Install the bootloader update (That have the USB boot capability)
4. Reboot
5. Create a bootable USB media

Now you can boot your Raspberry Pi 4 from the USB.

A more detailed description can be found here: https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/boot-raspberry-pi-4-usb

Comment: It would be great if you could go into a bit more detail on the steps as to whats needs to be done. currently it seems like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/419155/raspberry-booting-from-a-usb-pen-instead-of-an-sd-card#:~:text=Install%2Fburn%20the%20Linux%20distro,screen%20on%20an%20attached%20screen.) is what you mean for steps 2 and 3? If not could you provide some clarification please?

Comment: I have added a link to a more recent URL than the one you have found.

Comment: Thanks. That only works for people with a GUI though. I have managed to do it through a usb. I managed to get it working following [this](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2020/im-booting-my-raspberry-pi-4-usb-ssd) guy.